# Server information in a Flask app

Tags: python, flask

#### Intend

I want to be able to tell which server is running my Flask app.(Either Werkzeug or Gunicorn) And additionally if it is being proxied by NGINX or Apache.

#### Problem

I think I can get the response with JavaScript and get the server header, but In the case of it being proxy by NGINX or Apache, I won't be able to tell whatever is gunicorn or werkzeug that I is running under hood.

Is there a way to tell the server within the flask app?

Comment: Werkzeug is not a server that would be running your Flask app. Flask is based off Werkzeug which gives you utilities for WSGI. Gunicorn is a webserver that handles requests and send them to your Flask app. Most likely you have Nginx (or Apache) --> Gunicorn --> Flask App. Just as a clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some servers will add `SERVER_SOFTWARE` into the os environment. Gunicorn will do this.

```python
@app.route('/server')
def server():
    return os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I will wait a bit! Thanks 

Comment: and btw, a route should return a string not an object. I got i working with `return "%s" % os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE')`